# Recording a mp3 stream with FFMPEG and drop-outs

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, audio-streaming, live-streaming

I hope someone can give me pointer, I have a php script that runs the command below to record an live radio mp3 stream to create hour long mp3 recordings. It works very well for my purpose. The only issue is occasionally no recording is made. As far as I can tell its because the stream has dropped out and ffmpeg just aborts.

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i http://www.mystream.com:8000/radiostream.mp3 -t 60:00 -acodec copy /var/www/mydomain/audio/".$recorded_audio_title;
```

So my question, is there anyway to tell ffmpeg to continuously record for the 60:00 minutes to make a recording even if their are drop outs? I'd be happy with a odd bit of silence providing it completed the recording.

I hope this makes sense and I'd appreciate even a pointer to a FFMPEG option or flag. Having Google'd I havnt seen anything that would fit the bill.

Many thanks in advance

rob

Comment: do you want to complete dropped streams by silence to receive exactly 60 mins long recordings?

Comment: No, ideally it would be able to continue recording the stream when the stream reconnects. The drop-outs tend to only be very short. Although as a start, if no other alternative was available then a full length recording (even if some / large part was silence) would be better than nothing at all.

Comment: @Rob, you should verify that the stream isn't working, by using a packet sniffer.  Make sure that it is a connection error or something holding you up.  Also, you might consider achieving the same thing with simple WGET and stopping after 60 minutes.  It won't get you *exactly* 60 minutes as the server will initially push a buffer (generally 1MB), so you'll likely get 60 minutes + 1MB or so.  Also, don't worry about the MP3 corruption at the end.  Any player I've used this method with handles it just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to record exactly 60 mins files by completing dropped streaming by silence.

FFMPEG doesn't have such explicit option. But you can simulate it. Prepare 60 mins mp3 of silence. Record your stream. When recording finished, check its duration. If it's shorter than 60 mins - join your recording with silence file and specify that final duration should be 60 mins. [Joining is described here.](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#SEC27)

**EDIT:**

To continue recording you just need to check your previous recording duration and if it's too short - run the same FFMPEG command again, with different file name, and then join two files. Loop this until you receive 60 mins file

Comment: Thank you, for the suggestion. The problem is no file is created when theirs a drop out. For example say after 20 minutes theres a drop out with the stream, FFMPEG seems to just abort and not create any file - so I have nothing to join to. The ideal situation would be for FFMPEG not to fail on drop out and continue recording till the stream picked back up (one to a few second's later).

Comment: FFMPEG cannot do this. I can recommend you to record shorter pieces and then join them. In this case you'll lose less on drop out

Comment: if you save to raw audio then you might not "lose the stream" and not get any data...

Answer (score 0):

try looking at ffmpeg -segment command to split up your audio recording into 60 minute chunks [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment)